# What is the best practice to "re-render" a Component in React?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, frontend

I have an array of items mapped, and when I delete an item, it deletes in the database, and if I manually refresh the page it is gone. However, I want to "re-render" the list of items, once I click the delete button. From what I can find, is I need a state change to "re-render", so I tried setting up a boolean, but It doesn't "re-render". Any suggestions on best practice to achieve this result would be helpful.

```
class Profile extends Component {
  state = {
    username: '',
    movies: [],
    reRender: false    <---- by changing this state, I want a re-render of the component
  }

  getUserMovies = () => {
    const token = localStorage.usertoken;
    const decoded = jwt_decode(token);

    axios.post('/getusermovies', {
      user: decoded.username
    }).then(response => {
      this.setState({
        username: decoded.username,
        // movieName: response.data.moviename
        movies: response.data
      })
      console.log(response.data)
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error + "err in the front end getusermovies function")
    })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getUserMovies();
  }

  deleteMovie = (itemId) => {
    axios.post('/delete', {
      movie: itemId
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err + "in the deleteMovie function in front end" + itemId)
    })

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      reRender: !prevState.reRender  <------ This is where I am calling a state.
    }))
  }

  render() {
    let movies = this.state.movies;
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h1>{this.state.username}'s Movies: </h1>
        <div className="row">
          {movies.map(item =>
            <div className="profile-movies-box" >
              <img src={item.movie} alt='no image' className="movies-box-img" />
              <h4>{item.moviename}</h4>

              <button className="movie-buttons">
                <Link to={{
                  pathname: `/movie?movieName=${item.moviename}`,
                  state: { link: item.moviename }
                }}>View Movie</Link>
              </button>

              <button 
                className="movie-btn"
                value={item.moviename}
                onClick={() => { this.deleteMovie(item.moviename) }}
              >Delete Movie</button>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Profile;
```

Comment: You dont need a seperate state for re-render just filter out the movies when you click on delete, and call the delete API with the item to delete.

Comment: I figured it out. That is exactly what I did. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update movies array, remove item that has been deleted

```js
deleteMovie = (itemId) => {

    axios.post('/delete', {
        movie: itemId
    })
    .then(res => {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
         movies: prevState.movies.filter(m => m.id !== itemId)
      }));
    })
   .catch(err => {
        console.log(err + "in the delteMovie function in front end" + itemId)
    })
 }
```

I would recommend using async await

```js
deleteMovie = async (itemId) => {
  try {
   await axios.post('/delete', {
      movie: itemId
   });
   this.setState(prevState => ({
       movies: prevState.movies.filter(m => m.id !== itemId)
    }));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err + "in the delteMovie function in front end" + itemId)
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was needing to filter the original array. Makes so much sense now haha